# print crayon output colors in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to render colorful print outputs like what is displayed in the console? I want to use `waldo::compare()` in an app and can't seem to figure it out. I've found solutions to address messages or Rmds (`fansi`, `asciicast`) but I haven't had any luck. This example doesn't actually have a reactive input but the real app will.

```r
library(shiny)
library(waldo)

result <- 
  waldo::compare(
    letters[c(1, 2, 3)],
    letters[c(2, 2, 4)]
  )

result

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage( 
    shiny::verbatimTextOutput("waldo") 
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$waldo <- renderPrint({ 
      result
    })
    
  }
)
```

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Comment: you would have to convert those ANSI colors to HTML code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work. You need to use `fansi` and edit the `<pre>` tag:

```
library(shiny)
library(waldo)
library(fansi)

result <- 
  waldo::compare(
    letters[c(1, 2, 3)],
    letters[c(2, 2, 4)]
  )

result

ansi2html <- function(ansi){
  HTML(sprintf(
    "<pre>%s</pre>",
    gsub("\n", "<br/>", as.character(sgr_to_html(ansi)))
  ))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage( 
    htmlOutput("waldo") 
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$waldo <- renderUI({ 
      ansi2html(result)
    })
    
  }
)
```

[image]

If you are putting this in an Rmd, you'll need to add this:

````
```{r}
options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!